# Disable crontab's remove option in CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

How do I disable a specific command, for example `crontab -r`?

It happened to me twice already that I accidentally run that, because my <kbd>E</kbd> key is next to the <kbd>R</kbd> key.
That little typo is enough and your crontab is gone.

Comment: Don't forget to make backups of important files!

Comment: Sure, I have @daily zip -r /home/./scripts/cronjobs-all.zip /var/spool/cron/crontabs

Comment: A source code revision control system like Mercurial or Git would be even for managing script files and safe-guarding against accidental alteration or deletion. You don't even need a remote repository for either of the two. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a wrapper around the `crontab`command, for example this function would do:

```
crontab () { [[ $@ =~ -[iel]*r ]] && echo '"r" not allowed' || command crontab "$@" ;}
```

This function checks if `-r` exists in the argument of `crontab`; if so, exits with the message `"r" not allowed`, otherwise executes the command.

Put it in your `~/.bashrc` to get it loaded upon initialization of all interactive `bash` sessions.

Answer (score 28):

I suggest that you include

```
alias crontab="crontab -i"
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file (start a new shell before testing!)

This means that every time you run crontab, you always select the "-i" option. If you now give the `crontab -r` command, it is processed at `crontab -ir`, which prompts before removing the crontab file:

```
nick@serv2:~$ crontab -r
crontab: really delete nick's crontab? (y/n) n
```

Comment: `$ crontab -i` gives `Unknown option: i` on my webhost